# Handling Picture Uploads in IE 9

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET app. In my app, I need to upload 1 or more pictures. The pictures are associated with a product. The user enters the details of the product, uploads some pictures of the product, then clicks "Save". When the user clicks "Save", the product details get validated.

I need to be able to upload 1 or more pictures and show their thumbnails while a user is still editing product details. Is there a way to do this with IE 9? I saw [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/), however, it does not work with IE 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload files with IE9 you will need to POST a multipart form that contains an input of type file.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" />
</form>
```

Then you have to write a bunch of JavaScript to get the functionality working with thumbnails etc. while the user is still filling in details.

Basically you would have to submit the form when a file is chosen to be uploaded. For this you can listen to the "change" event of the file input. After you submitted the form and the server has created a thumbnail and stored the image you can create an img tag with the thumbnail as src. For this you can use a JQuery version that supports IE9.